# Unable to .empty() the appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
state.on('change', function(){
    city.empty();
    $.getJSON("pincodes.JSON", function(pincodes){
        var key = state.val(); 
        for (var j= 0; j < pincodes['address'].length; j++) {
            if (pincodes['address'][j]['circlename'] == key) {
                temp.push(pincodes['address'][j]['regionname']);
            }
        } 
        cities = $.unique(temp);
        for (var k = 0; k < cities.length; k++) {   
            city.append('<option>' + cities[k] + '</option>');
        }  
    });
});
```

In the above `state = $('#state')` , the above works fine fills the cities on select "state" . But the issue is when a new state is selected the previously filled cities are also there . Even though I tried *.empty* on every `change(`) .

Comment: Do you empty your `temp` array? Something like `temp = []` in the beginning of this function.

Comment: temp array fetches all the cities in the json , I just need to the empty my <select> on evenry change() and then append () .

Comment: So, the user changes `state`, you loop through your `pincodes` and fill `temp` array. Next time, when this handler fires, `temp` array is not empty.

Comment: I think @YeldarKurmangaliyev is right. Try to empty `temp` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Thanks , that works .But can you explain why 
        cities = $.unique(temp); does not delete the repetitive values ?

Comment: What is `city` exactly? Maybe you can do `city.html('')` to empty it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't empty your `temp` array. So, every time this function is called, you keep appending items to your `temp` array.

You simply need to add the following line in your code:

```
state.on('change', function() {
    city.empty();
    temp = []; // <---
    $.getJSON("pincodes.JSON", function(pincodes) {
```

What about `cities = $.unique(temp);`, it won't work.
According to **[`jQuery.unique()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)** documentation, this function

> Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers.

So, it is not a correct usage. If you get non-unique values from your JSON, you will need to use another way to get distinct values. There is a good [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array) on this topic.

Comment: Thanks , cities = $.unique(temp); works for uniques values in my case . I fetch from json in temp which is not unique . the values I get in cities are unique . The only issue was it was not working when change fired more than once . and thanks for the help , it really worked .